# Series summation proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I deduced that
$$\frac{1}{e^x-1}\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{e^x-e^{\frac{2\pi i s}{n}}}=\frac{\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}(n-s)e^{(n-s-1)x}}{e^{nx}-1}$$
Now, I want to get an analytic proof of this deduced result.

Comment: There are certainly some misprints in the statement ($x$ in the numerator on the right?). Anyhow, use that $z^n-1=\prod_{s=0}^{n-1}(z-e^{2\pi i s/n})$.

Comment: How did you "deduce" that?

Comment: I tried several values for  n -(math. induction)

Comment: Hmmmmm... $ $ $ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will use a slight modification of the identity mentioned in my comment above:
$$\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=\prod_{s=1}^{n-1}(z-e^{2\pi is/n}).$$
Taking the logarithm, differentiating, and multiplying by $\frac{1}{z-1}$, we find
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z-1}\sum_{s=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{z-e^{2\pi is/n}}&=\frac{1}{z-1}\frac{d}{dz}\ln
\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}=\\
&=\frac{1}{z-1}\cdot \frac{z-1}{z^n-1}\cdot\frac{d}{dz}\left[1+z+z^2+\ldots+z^{n-1}\right]=\\
&=\frac{1}{z^n-1}\left[1+2z+3z^2+\ldots+(n-1)z^{n-2}\right].
\end{align}
Now setting $z=e^x$ gives the necessary result.